# Android camera ensure fast response onPictureTaken

Tags: android, camera

I have created a custom camera activity (pretty much followed the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture)) 
I implemented a SurfaceView to use a preview and an ImageView to display the image taken on OnPictureTaken

Picture taken takes a while to show up and differs from the preview in terms of aspect ratio, size, lighting, white balance. (probably I didn't set the params properly). The quality of the picture doesn't really matter to me. I just want the app to be responsive, ie **still picture shows up immediately, and is identical to the preview.**

So what I ended up doing was remove the ImageView and only have the SurfaceView. When the camera button is clicked, I stopPreview(). However, now I don't know how to save the SurfaceView content to bitmap/file. From what I read there isn't really a way to SurfaceView to return a bitmap.

What would be a better way to implement the camera? To reiterate, I need to be able to get a bitmap that is identical to the preview, and have that still image shown to the user immediately.

Comment: "still picture shows up immediately, and is identical to the preview" -- then capture a preview frame, using the API for it on `Camera`.

Comment: Usually, if the Picture parameters and Preview parameters are same, `onPictureTaken()` will produce a picture quickly, and have the same field of view. It may have better focus and contrast, also white balance, but that's usually because the preview was not good enough. If you insist on using preview image, consider calling [Camera.OneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)) and freeze the Surface in its callback